# How to separate out below tightly coupled classes

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, coupling

I have two classes which are somewhat tightly coupled to one another. Lets call them A and B. A derives from C and B derives from D.

B is the class whose instance is created by the system and then B in turn creates instance of A and also starts executing an application that B will interact and control execution of.

All the logic that B needs is in A and A also has all the supporting objects that are needed to perform the actions requested by A.

Now B is becoming kind of like the omniscient class which is not good. I am planning to separate out the logic in B and also moe the important objects needed to pereform actions out from B to a registry. Please note that the important objects that B holds are public and can be used by other classes if needed.

Now the way I am planning on doing it is that move all the important objects in B to a registry which can be accessed by other as well. Move all the logic needed by A into A itself (we thought of moving it out to a separate class but decided to just move it out to A). Still since B derives from D, there are some functionalities that we are deriving from D that needs to stay in B which are needed to perform actions requested by A.

Apologies for the long description, I would request you to critique on whether moving the important objects out to registry will be a good idea. if not what will be the better way. Another thing would be since A and B need each other they will be coupled but what will be the better way to proceed keeping the logic in A and referring to B for only the functionalitites it is deriving from D?

To add A is curently a thin layer which received requests over the newtwork and asks B to perform those actions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a dependency injection framework? It sounds like B is taking on a lot of the responsibility a framework like that would provide. But a general first step in breaking classes that reference each other is to factor out an `interface` for A, and create a factory that instantiates A and B, and passes A as the interface to B in the constructor (or with a setter). Also, you might do well to draw a simple boxes-and-arrows diagram with your classes and the classes they have references to. In your diagram, break up any loops with the same interface/factory combo.

Comment: But the key idea here is "dependency injection". Sounds like your app is complex enough that it could really benefit from that.

Comment: We are not using a DI framework, for certain reasons we don't wanna do that.

May be a silly question to ask, but would you please elaborate on what specific advantage we will gain from having a factory. Having an interface will probably do just enough I guess?

Comment: If B has a reference to A' as an interface, but is still instantiating a concrete A, then A and B still have a cyclic dependency. Externalizing the creation logic provides decoupling and simplifies your code. There's a lot more to read about DI, but really you can get lots of the benefits of DI without going with one of the frameworks.

Comment: ...maybe a simpler way to put it is to cite the "single responsibility" principle. Right now B is creating *and* using A, but the single responsibility would be to just use A & let someone else create it.

Comment: I see, thanks or explaining, having a factory to separate out the dependeincies is a realy good idea. Thanks